# Execute iOS simulator for an Expo project run on a Windows computer on the same network

Tags: react-native, expo

Currently developing an Expo project on Windows computer using Visual Studio Code, and I want to simulate the project with iOS simulator on my Mac computer on which I have already installed XCode and iOS simulator. However, as the project is saved on my Windows computer, there is no way to run it on my mac computer unless I copy the project to the Mac computer. My question is if it is possible to start a simulator for the project run on a different computer on the same network? In this specific case, I want to run the project on my Windows, and simulate it with iOS simulator on my Mac. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its better if you just transfer your React Native code to your Mac or just use usb and transfer through Dropbox or P-Cloud. but to answer your question i don't really know much about firewall but if you disable firewall you can get the ip or url and you can go to your mac and go to that link...

**But** i really suggest for you not to do it because other people can go to your link as well and hackers can **hack** you...

I really recommend to just transfer your react native code instead...

Comment: Thank you. I set firewall and tried to access through network but ended up failing because URL scheme is expo://. As you recommended, I built an expo environment on my mac and run the project from there.

Answer (score 0):

You can just run your expo project in tunnel mode and connect manually via the connection string to your IOS simulator running on your mac.

Comment: How can I do this?